# multiple RewriteRules in htaccess file, the first one over writes the second one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to run `multiple RewriteRules` in my `htaccess` file.

**however, the `first RewriteRule`, overwrites the `second RewriteRule` for some reason!**

this is what i have in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ items.php?itemsurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ items.php?itemsurl=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ blog.php?blogurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ blog.php?blogurl=$1 [L]
```

the first RewriteRule works fine but if I click on the links for `blog.php?blogurl=` it will simply take me to the `items.php`!

I could put the RewriteRules for the blog.php at the top of the htaccess file and put the RewriteRules for items.php bellow it and it will make the blog.php rewriterule work for blog.php but it will make the rewriterules for the items.php stop working and everything will point to the blog.php page!

**So basically, only the first `RewriteRule` in the `htaccess` file works and it will overwrite the second one somehow.**

could someone advise on this please?

Comment: You use [L], thats why any other rules will be skiped

Comment: @user3132718, it doesn't really matter. i could remove the [L] and still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Remove the first one, and in the second, add a `?` after `/`, it should look like this: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/?$ items.php?itemsurl=$1 [L]`. That makes the `/` optional. Do this for the third and the fourth one.

Comment: @user3132718, still no affect unfortunately.

Comment: If URI is `/abc.html` do you want it to be handled by `/items.php` OR `/blog.php`?

Comment: @anubhava, the `items.php` is a page for items and `blog.php` is a blogs page. so the `abc.html` will only point to one or the other and NOT both.

Comment: Exactly my point. But your rules are using same pattern to rewrite to `/items.php and /blog.php`. Only first rule will work in this case.

Comment: @anubhava, okay, I understand but is there a workaround for this? I'm not really good with htaccess file and its Rules! any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to define your requirement clearly. Obviously same URI pattern cannot be rewritten to 2 targets.

Comment: @anubhava, basically, what i am trying to do is to convert `http://domain.com/items.php?itemsurl=somenameFORitems.html` AND `http://domain.com/blog.php?blogurl=somenameFORblogs.html` TO `http://domain.com/somenameFORitems.html` AND `http://domain.com/somenameFORblogs.html`. i think i might need to add something like domain.com/blog/ for blogs URL and domain.com/items/ for items URL?

Comment: Yes i if you agree to add blog and items in URL then it will work. If you want i can pay an answer for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)\.html\/?$ items.php?itemsurl=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)\.html\/?$ blog.php?blogurl=$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` affects only to the first `RewriteRule`.

The apache variables should be in these brakes: `{}`, not these `()`
And one more thing - to check `.` you should escape it so: `\.`

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, you can use following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^items/([\w-]+)\.html\/?$ items.php?itemsurl=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)\.html\/?$ blog.php?itemsurl=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```